# Render add node form within module output

Tags: 7, forms

I have a content type called “osago”. And I have a module that outputs some things.

How can I output the *create this content type* form within this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `drupal_render()` on `node_add()` result.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$content = node_add('osago');
print drupal_render($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  print node_add('osago');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $content=node_add('osago');
?>
```

etc etc (you may or may not need the module_load_include() depending on how you've set your module up, too)

Comment: node_add('osago') returns Array.
How can I print it?

Comment: and when I execute these two lines my main title is altered.

Answer (score 0):

drupal_set_message() or (dsm() if you have devel installed) is your friend...

```
<?php
  $content=node_add('osago');
  drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($content,true) . '</pre>');
?>
```

...and in this case will print out in your theme's message area the structure of a variable, and from that you should be able to see what's going on.